Theory about *bad* correlation or downside correlation
For fund of funds comparing the returns of two funds and measuring their correlation. It is good correlation when they both go up and bad correlation when they both go down. So if B and C have the same correlation to our existing fund A, but main contribution of cor(AB) is the good days while main contribution of cor(AC) is the bad days, we would prefer to add B to the portfolio.
Is there an adjusted 'correlation' measure to take that into account? Can I remove the data points when both A and B are positive and calculate the correlation of remaining data?

You can also check semi-correlations in which direction of price movements are taken into account. Similar concepts like semi-variance and semi-covariance and semi-beta are also well studied in the literature.
Paper:
Bollerslev, Patton, Zhang: Equity clusters through the lens of realized semicorrelations.
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.econlet.2021.110245

I think you are looking for the "asymmetric correlation". The most basic approach is to first identify regimes, like "severe bear market" or "mild bull market", to split up the history into the regimes, and then to calculate Pearson's $\rho$ separately under each regime.  There are more complicated approaches, not necessarily giving better insight. Some relevant papers:
Longin, Solnik. Extreme correlation of international equity markets. https://doi.org/10.1111/0022-1082.00340
Campbell, Koedijk, Kofman. Increased Correlation in Bear Markets. https://doi.org/10.2469/faj.v58.n1.2512
Jondeau. Asymmetry in tail dependence in equity portfolios. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2015.02.014
